# Comparing Two tables for data relation

Tags: php, mysql

My SQL query is:

```
UPDATE REGISTRUDENT set qual=1  
                WHERE studentolevelsubjects AS sls
                INNER JOIN courserequirements AS csreq ON sls.subject_id = csreq.subject_id
                WHERE sls.stud_id = '$stud_id' AND sls.grade_id>=csreq.min_grade AND sls.examno = '$examno' AND csreq.course_id = '$course_id'
```

I'm having issue comparing two different table to get if a registrant qualified based on the course requirement I need help

course requirement table

[image: course requirement table]
The subject passed by the student in exams
[image: The subject passed by the student in exams]

I intend updating and setting the qual =1 if the student qualifies

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your query syntax is not correct. It rather should be

```
UPDATE REGISTRUDENT rs   
JOIN studentolevelsubjects sls ON sls.some_column = rs.some_column //missing this JOIN
JOIN courserequirements csreq ON sls.subject_id = csreq.subject_id
AND sls.grade_id >= csreq.min_grade 
WHERE sls.stud_id = '$stud_id'  
AND sls.examno = '$examno' 
AND csreq.course_id = '$course_id'
SET rs.qual = 1;
```

Comment: I want the query to ensure that if ALL the course subjects are not done by the student or he/she get a lower grade there is A PROMPT OR RETURN FALSE

Comment: NO, you can't do that in query rather you will have to have that prompt in your application logic.

Comment: Isn't there a way I can check if the user met all the subject requirement using the query?

Comment: @nollyvenon, may be but that's a separate question which should be posted separately.

Comment: but thats what i want to achieve. the subject the students did is compared with the course selecrs.qual = 1ted requirements and if the requirement is met then rs.qual=1